# No response on paypal api with php curl

Tags: php, api, curl, paypal

I'm trying to get the response from the PayPal api regarding an order with php and cURL. Here is my code, I have of course replaced the token, which is not the problem here.
With the following command, everything works fine in my terminal, I don't understand why it doesn't work. (If I do a `var_dump($response)`, I get `string(0) ""`.

Code :

```php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/".$_GET['transacid']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $headers = [
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer my_oauth_token"
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response= curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($response);
```

And, the CLI command :

```sh
curl -v -X GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/my_order_id\
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer my_oauth_token"
```

I think I can get the result with an exec(), but it's really not clean, especially with a GET variable.

Thanks !

Comment: Just a remark that might not be related but in the terminal, you are doing a GET request while on the php side you are doing a POST request (cf. CURLOPT_POST which is set to 1). So you are not doing the same type of request already. First do that and then we can troubleshoot further if needed.

Comment: Uh i'm so dumb... It works !

Comment: Glad that my comment helped. Now, as a good Stackoverflow buddy, I would suggest marking your issue as resolved. And eventually, you could also mark my answer as the one that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting as answer after commenting)

Just a remark that might not be related but in the terminal, you are doing a GET request while on the php side you are doing a POST request (cf. CURLOPT_POST which is set to 1). So you are not doing the same type of request already. First do that and then we can troubleshoot further if needed. And eventually, that might be the only thing causing your issue.